# 1997 Chevy Camaro, remote start works but key does not

Tags: electrical, starting, power, camaro, remote-start

My car won't start, no sound, no click, nothing, but all power is on, and the remote start will start the car, but not the key. What could be the issue?

Comment: Is this factory remote start or aftermarket?

Comment: Failed ignition switch maybe? Or perhaps a wiring issue with the remote start module? When did this problem start?

Comment: Is there any additional information you can add to your question?  Any troubleshooting steps you have undertaken?  Thanks and welcome to the site!  Cheers.

Comment: It is Excalibur, after market

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was wondering if the neutral safety switch (auto) or clutch start switch (manual) is out (depending on your tranny). Your remote start would not be factory (didn't make them factory). It could be installed to bypass the neutral safety/clutch start, in fact if it is a manual car, it would be wired that way so you wouldn't have to have the clutch depressed to get it to start. Really, that's where I'd start your diagnostic. It seems like the most reasonable place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the ignition switch, but it could possibly be a fuse.  A couple things to test.

Check any fuses related to starting.

I think I would start by removing the steering column cover so you can access the ignition switch and wiring.  Get a test light or multimeter and verify you are getting power in.  Turn the switch to various positions and verify you are getting power out.

If you are not getting power in, the issue is before the switch (likely a fuse).  If you are not getting power out, the switch is the issue.

You could grab a switch from the junkyard and swap it in to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the factory wiring diagram, so there are several possibilities why it will not start with the key. If it has an aftermarket remote start system this can make diagnosis more complicated depending on how it was integrated into the starting circuit.

[image]